# SQL Server 2012 / Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Does SQL Server 2012 include Visual Studio?

P.S. I don't mean to be an idiot, but I can't find the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not include Visual Studio. If you do a full install with all the client tools you get some bare minimum shell stuff but that is just scaffolding to support things like Management Studio. Visual Studio proper is a separate product and must be licensed separately.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't come with Visual Studio.

SQL Server is a database server. The install media comes with some tooling, like [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio).

Visual Studio is an IDE, an Integrated Development Environement. It *can* connect to SQL Server and used when developing database driven applications.

But the two are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

It will come with Business Intelligence Design Stuido, commonly known as BIDS, which is built around the Visual Studio framework.

If you need a dev evnironment, you can check out [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)